# D3.js How to customize legend in bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use following code within a for loop to push data into array and this data used to build grouped bar chart using D3.js.

```js
DataSetForBarChart.push({
          TestSuite: "TS"+treeIndex,
          Pass: trueAppear,
          Fail: falseAppear,
          FalseStatements : falseStatement,
          TrueStatements : trueStatement
     });
```

I used only Pass and Fail for grouped bar chart. It nicely appear.
 But when I set legend It show last 4 things. But I realy need to show Pass and Fail only. How to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```js
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(testSuite.slice(0,2)) // give which elements that you need to set legend inside slice method
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });
```